# how to intercept jquery datatables search function to reload data before searching (what is the name of the function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, interceptor

So, I am using datatables for displaying my data. To get consistent data, I need to reload my data with an ajax-request if my search field is in focus or when the first character is entered.

So I thought about intercepting the whole built-in search function somehow like this:

```
var oldFunc=jQuery.fn.Datatable.?;
jQuery.fn.Datatable.?=function(){

$.get(Url, function(data){
    oldFunc()
    })
}
```

But now I don't know which function exactly I have to intercept.
Apart from that I think it's a very common use-case and I just miss the "right way" on how to achieve this. So, if there's another approach, I would be glad to hear from you.

Best regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTables handles search as a filter.  There's convenient access to the array of filters to be applied,  `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering`. More info here:  http://datatables.net/development/filtering#global_filters.